# Document angular.js app with docular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, documentation

I have some troubles with documenting my app. I'm using http://grunt-docular.com/ and its markup to document my modules.

However, when it comes to methods that are part of a service for example, the angular.js documentation itself is in a different markup, than docular suggested.

For example, in the angularjs source code, you'll find a documentation like this:

```
  /**
   * @ngdoc method
   * @name ng.$q#defer
   * @kind function
   *
   * @description
   * Creates a `Deferred` object which represents a task which will finish in the future.
   *
   * @returns {Deferred} Returns a new instance of deferred.
   */
```

Looking at `@name` you see that `defer` is a method of the `ng.$q` module. But when I use the syntax with a hashtag `#`, it is interpreted as an extra module, e.g.

```
/**
 * @ngdoc service
 * @name myApp.service:myService
 * @description
 * some description
 */
angular.module('myApp').service('myService', function() {
  return {
    /**
     * @ngdoc method
     * @name myApp.service:myService#fetch
     * @description
     * Some description
     */
    fetch: function(forceUpdate) {
    }
  };
}]);
```

becomes in the documentation `myService#fetch`. But when using `@methodOf` like this, it works:

```
/**
 * @ngdoc service
 * @name myApp.service:myService
 * @description
 * some description
 */
angular.module('myApp').service('myService', function() {
  return {
    /**
     * @ngdoc method
     * @name fetch
     * @methodOf myApp.service:myService
     * @description
     * Some description
     */
    fetch: function(forceUpdate) {
    }
  };
}]);
```

Why is this? Is this the wrong way to document my services? And why does it work within the angular code?

Comment: Same for me except that even using @methodOf does not work, It puts the method under the module and not under the service.